# In chess diagram en passent is sometimes not printed out

Tags: xskak

In some cases the printed chess notation does not include the en passant remark "e.p.".
The image shows two different chess positions.

In the upper row the notation of white's move 2 includes the e.p.

In the lower row  the notation of black's move 1 does not include the e.p.

[image: Two examples with en passant]

Here is the code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{a4}
    \usepackage[german, ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[LSBC4,T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{chessboard}
    \usepackage{xskak}
    \setboardfontencoding{LSBC4}
    \newskaklanguage{german}{KDTLSB}
    \skaklanguage[german]        


    \begin{document}        
    \newchessgame[
        id=LoesungA2,
        setfen=1n2B1n1/bp1pp1pb/7k/1p2q3/5P2/2pK4/1r6/2B5,
        moveid=1w
    ]
    \hidemoves{1.f4f5+ g7g5 2. f5xg6+}%

    En passant is printed out correctly in move 2

    \noindent
    \xskakloop[step=1]{%
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \chessboard[smallboard, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]
            \\
            \xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}%
        \end{tabular}
    }
    \vspace{5ex}



    \newchessgame[
        id=LoesungA3,
        setfen=1n2B1n1/bp1pp2b/6Pk/1p2q3/4p3/2p1K3/1r1P4/2B5,
        moveid=1w
    ]
    \hidemoves{1. d4  e4xd3++  2.Kxd3+}%

    En passant is not printed out in black's move 1

    \noindent
    \xskakloop[step=1]{%
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \chessboard[smallboard, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]
            \\
            \xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}%
        \end{tabular}
    }
    \end{document}
```

I use:

/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xskak/xskak.sty

Package: xskak 2015/01/02 version v1.4 extended chess typesetting and parsing

Did I something wrong or is it a bug?

Extra question:
In the lower example after taking e.p. there is a double check (Queen and Bishop).
In the hidemove command I wrote e4xd3++. However, in the notation the second chess mark does not appear.